# How to prevent SwiftUI DetailView from crashing when deleting the last entity from CoreData collection?

Tags: macos, swiftui, core-data, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationsplitview

I have a CoreData entity called TestItem:

[image]

If there's 1 entity in collection, deleting this entity will crash the app with an error: "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x197c0b8b4)". As it seems, nothing will prevent DetailView from crashing once it's been initialized with ObservedObject, which cannot be nil. I can't find a way to deinit DetailView before deleting the object. To have more information why I couldn't deinit DetailView, see my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76050610/how-to-trigger-ondisappear-event-for-a-view-inside-foreach-loop-in-swiftui?noredirect=1#comment134154882_76050610)

Here is a code example reproducing the error as following:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    let persistence = PersistenceController.shared
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: TestItem.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TestItem.date, ascending: false)])
    var items: FetchedResults<TestItem>
    
    @State var selectedItem: TestItem?
    @State var selectedItemIndex: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selectedItem) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(item.name)
                            .foregroundColor(selectedItem == item ? .blue : .white)
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedItem = item
                        selectedItemIndex = items.firstIndex(of: item)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button(action: {
                    addItem()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.square")
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            if let selectedItem = selectedItem {
                DetailView(item: selectedItem, onDelete: {
                    guard !items.isEmpty else {
                        self.selectedItem = nil
                        selectedItemIndex = nil
                        return
                    }
                    
                    if selectedItemIndex! > items.indices.last! {
                        selectedItemIndex = selectedItemIndex! - 1
                    }
                    
                    self.selectedItem = items[selectedItemIndex!]
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        let newItem = TestItem(context: persistence.container.viewContext)
        newItem.name = "Test Item"
        newItem.date = Date()
        
        do {
            try persistence.container.viewContext.save()
            selectedItem = newItem
            selectedItemIndex = 0
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var item: TestItem
    var onDelete: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(item.name)
            
            DatePicker("Date", selection: $item.date, displayedComponents: [.date])
            
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    deleteItem(item)
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteItem(_ item: TestItem) {
        item.managedObjectContext?.delete(item)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do {
                try item.managedObjectContext?.save()
                onDelete()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error deleting data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this [Desitation View loading without tap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61234030/4080925).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the crashed is caused by the `DatePicker` that I guess holds a strong reference to the `Item` object. If we break this reference the app will not crash when the last object is deleted.

This can be done by using a `State` object instead for the `DatePicker` selection

```
@State private var selectedDate: Date = .now
```

used here

```
DatePicker("Date", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
```

and update the `item` when this property is changed

```
.onChange(of: selectedDate) { date in
    item.date = date
}
```

We also need to update `selectedDate` when a new `TestItem` object is selected in the sidebar

```
.onChange(of: item) { newItem in
    selectedDate = newItem.date
}
```

I don't know if this relevant for any other components than the `DatePicker`, I for instance changed so that I could edit the name attribute using a `TextField` but that didn't cause any issues so it's definitely not an issue for all components where you can mutate the content.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach will create another problem with detecting changes and transferring selectedDate state to item. If I use .onChange detecting change of item.objectID to update selectedDate, I will not be able to detect changes in selectedDate without unwanted behavior when first .onChange will trigger the second .onChange and will overwrite item.date with previous selectedDate value.

Comment: Yes I also had some issues with date but I thought it was beyond the question to solve that as well. Maybe I can take a look at it again.

Comment: A simple `onChange(of:)` fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. And I will have to use a flag to prevent triggering .onChange(of: selectedDate) right after .onChange(of: item) changed selectedDate.